# Excel VBA Change Next Cell Text Color ERROR

Tags: vba, excel, offset

Excel VBA 2010

This is a quick function that when the user click on a cell (A Column), it creates a checkmark. I also want the function to make the text in adjacent cell (B column) change color.

I'm currently getting this error: 
`Run-time error '9': Subscript out of Range`
It highlights this line:
`Target.Offset(0,1).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(77, 191, 46)`

Here's the full code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A3:A20")) Is Nothing Then
        Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
            If Target = vbNullString Then
                Target = "a"
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(77, 191, 46)
            Else
                Target = vbNullString
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Any Advice??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.Interior.ColorIndex` to `.Font.Color` and that should do :)